# PHP / Smarty - Identifying an empty "foreach"

Tags: php, smarty

Here is my current code:

```
{php} foreach($result as $key=>$value)

{ echo "<div class='internalpadding'>";

{/php}

This is a test.

{php} } {/php}
```

This code is displaying "This is a test." a specific amount of times in a row - one time for each post a user has in the database.  That part is working perfectly.

However, if a user has no posts, there's simply nothing displayed.  This makes sense, since it should just be displaying text for posts that do exist.  But is there a way I can make it give some type of message like "There are no posts for this user" if nothing is found using `foreach`?

Comment: There is `{foreach}` and `{foreachelse}` in smarty http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl Your code is weird: it's odd to take a template engine then use php in templates

Comment: Lol yea, unfortunately the PHP files are encrypted so I'm kind of stuck making tweaks within the template files.

Comment: Okay they are. I just said that using `{php}` in templates is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($result == null)
 echo "There are no posts for this user" ;
else {
       foreach($result as $key=>$value)

         { echo "<div class='internalpadding'>";
           echo "This is a test" ; }
}
```

Comment: The question is about `smarty` specifically, not pure php. `$result == null` check is silly btw. As soon as it's an array one must check its size instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use {foreachelse}

```
{foreach $result as $post}
    <h2>{$post->title}</h2>
    <p>{$post->text}</p>
{foreachelse}
    There are no posts for this user
{/foreach}
```

Oficial Doc:
https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Answer (score 0):

```
{if $result|@count == 0}
 There are no posts for this user
{else}
  {foreach from=$result item=$post}
    <h2>{$post->title}</h2>
    <p>{$post->text}</p>
  {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Why not use just smarty